# User band management

Tags: views, nodes, 8, dashboard

I have a content type of band. I have a view filtering by user id to see my bands.

What I'm trying to accomplish is allowing users to create a band and have a management dashboard. This dashboard would be separate from their public facing page.

I would like the dashboard to have the ability to add shows, members, photos etc all on the same screen.

My guess would be to create a page with multiple views filtered based on some type of criteria either a reference field to members or the single node author.

Is there a better approach to handling this type of functionality?

Comment: Kiamlaluno i understand if this is too broad, but where then can we have said conversations? Not trying to be defensive just curious?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about relationships between the different entities or content types like users, bands, shows and so on. You build this relationships with reference fields.

For the dashboard you don't need necessarily views.

When you use a reference field to another entity you can configure in the display mode to render the referenced entities. Then you can configure the display mode of the referenced entity, which can contain itself other reference fields which you then configure in the same way and so on.

So you can build and theme the complete dashboard without views by only showing the parent entity.

Though at some point you probably need views, as view block in a header, footer or sidebar or from the start as view page, if you need more options for filtering. The entities displayed in these views can contain again rendered reference fields. This is how you combine these tools to build the layout you want.